# Как проверить содержится ли строка в HTML файле?

Tags: spring-boot, юнит-тесты

Я хочу сделать тест при помощи spring boot

```
@Test
    public void testMainPage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string((containsString("Description"))));

    }
```

Использую вот эти зависимости

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
```

Но когда я запускаю, выдает ошибку

```
java: incompatible types: org.springframework.test.web.client.RequestMatcher cannot be converted to org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher
```

Я могу явно указать ResultMatcher

```
   .andExpect((ResultMatcher) content().string((containsString("Description"))));
```

И тогда он выдает

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.test.web.client.match.ContentRequestMatchers$$Lambda$1681/0x000000080194d1f0 cannot be cast to class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher (org.springframework.test.web.client.match.ContentRequestMatchers$$Lambda$1681/0x000000080194d1f0 and org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Как проверить что у меня на странице содержится какая то фраза?